# How can I show that this function is integrable?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $r>0$ and $$f \colon \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty), \,x \mapsto \mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty)}\cdot \exp (-r\cdot x).$$
In order to compute the moments of an exponentially distributed random variable $X$, I would like to show that $p\cdot f$ is integrable wrt. the Lebesgue measure for every polynomial $p$. Intuitionally, this is clear to me, but how can I show it formally?

Comment: First check it is measurable. This is given for free as it is continuous. Then to check integrability, you just integrate its absolute value (which is just f) and show that it is finite.

Comment: (What this really boils down to is showing every integral $\int_0^{\infty} x^k \exp(-rx)dx$ is finite). This can be done via induction (integration by parts differentiating the $x^k$ term)

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show that $x \mapsto x^k f(x)$ is integrable for $k \geq 1$. Measurability is clear because the functions which we are dealing with are continuous.

Fix some $s \in (0,r)$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. If $x \geq 0$, then by the definition of the exponential function

$$\exp(sx) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(sx)^n}{n!} \geq s^k \frac{x^k}{k!},$$

i.e.

$$x^k \leq s^{-k} k! \exp(sx), \qquad x \geq 0.$$

Consequently,

$$|x^k f(x)| \leq s^{-k} k! \exp(-(r-s)x), \qquad x \geq 0.$$

Since $s$ is strictly smaller than $r$, we have $r-s>0$, and so

$$\int_{[0,\infty)} |x^k f(x)| \, dx \leq s^{-k} k!  \int_{[0,\infty)} \exp(-(r-s)x) \, dx < \infty.$$